# Unable to bridge network connection to any hypervisor

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vmware, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a Virtual-PC hard drive that I need to run with bridged networking so that it gets an IP address on the same network the host OS is running on. However, on this particular computer, I am finding that to be impossible.

**Host OS**
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit, Service Pack 1
Network Adapter: Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection

**Virtual PC**
When trying to edit the settings of any virtual machine, I receive the following error:

> 3.0_SP2 - Windows Virtual PC Settings
>   The virtual network ID could not be retrieved.
>   Error 0xa0040702 occurred.

After that, the only networking options I have are NAT and internal

**VirtualBox 4.2.2**
VirtualBox allows me to select Bridged as the networking, but it fails to open the VM:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Virtual ATM.
>
> Failed to open/create the internal network
>   'HostInterfaceNetworking-Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection'
>   (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).
>
> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005) Component: Console Interface:
>   IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}

**VMware Player 5.0.0**
I've tested VMware with a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit. It starts up fine in bridged mode, but Ubuntu cannot complete a network connection.

What can I do to fix whatever seems to be wrong with my computer that is breaking all three of these hypervisors' Bridged network modes?

Comment: What type of device are you trying to bridge to? Ethernet NIC? Wi-Fi?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem with VPC's moved to a new computer. For the solution I just went to the "Settings" and changed the "Network Adapter" to none and exited. Then I went back and changed them to One (1) and selected "NAT" and this seemed to fix my problems.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).